# Python - How to carry out string operations?

Tags: python, string

Code:

```
str="Hello World"         
for i in range(len(str)):                  
  str[i]=str[len(str)-i]    
print(str)
```

This corresponds to an error in Python.
What would be the right way to implement this?

Comment: What is your expected output ? what do you want to achieve ? what is the error ? **What is the question?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Is this, by any chance, a homework assignment?

Comment: nope, im just learning python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In Python, strings are immutable. You can't reassign individual characters.
2. `str` is not a good variable name because it masks the built-in function `str()`.
3. It looks like you want to reverse the string:

---

```
string = "Hello World"
reversed_string = string[::-1]
```

Comment: Thank you, but i actually wanted the mirror image of the string along its center. Can you help?

Comment: Mirroring both ends along the center is equivalent to reversing it. If you want something else, please clarify the expected input and output.

Answer (score 1):

try to following:

```
string = "Hello World"
print string[::-1]
print ''.join(reversed(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I think the key problem of you is that you  don't understand that string  in python is immutable, yet you can read  str[i] but this don't mean that you can change str[i],never do this:
`one_string = "..."
one_string[i] = ".."`

remember `one_string[i]` is read only.
You can just use some standard lib funcion to replace part of the string, but some thing like `one_string[i] = "..."` is absolutely wrong.